# Bootstrap 4 - How to make a column stretch to the height of the parent?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want to create a card that contains an image slideshow, with an accompanying description div on the side. I was trying to get the description div to fill up to the same height as the image beside it.

Currently, the description `div` simply takes up as much height as its contents require, but I want it to expand to fill the parent `div`.

I tried applying `flex-grow` and setting `style="flex: 1 1 auto"` to the `flex-column` `div` but it doesn't seem to be changing anything.

I found a few posts addressing having rows filling the height of a parent `div` but none for columns.

I'm currently using `w-100` as well, to have the column fill the remaining width of the parent `div`, but for some reason `h-100` doesn't seem to work the same way.

HTML with Bootstrap 4.1.1 min.css:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
    <div class="flex-row card-body d-flex flex-fill align-items-center">
      <!-- Description Div -->
      <div class="flex-column d-flex w-100  flex-fill align-items-end showborder">
        <div class="p-2 ">
          <!-- Project Title -->
          <strong class="p-2 ">Title Text</strong>
          <!-- GitHub Link -->
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 w-100 ">
          <!-- Project Description -->
          <p>
            Description text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-auto p-2 ">
          <!-- Link to Project -->
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#">Check it out</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Image Carousel -->
      <div class="carousel slide showborder" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner ">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100 " src="res/testimg1.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100 " src="res/testimg2.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you want the image height as text height??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the height of the text column to fill parent row height you can just add to it `self-align:stretch`.

See this in action: https://codepen.io/matteopieroni/pen/MXdGja

Then you will have to make adjustments in the column children to get the look you are after!

Answer (score 0):

If this can be of your any help.
This align image beside the card.

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ctudb8o6/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="card-group">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-left" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22286%22%20height%3D%22180%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20286%20180%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_164697f30e4%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A14pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_164697f30e4%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22286%22%20height%3D%22180%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22107.1953125%22%20y%3D%2296.271875%22%3E286x180%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```